# Clustering before regression

Tags: regression, clustering, unsupervised-learning, supervised-learning

Could there be any benefit to running a clustering algorithm on a data set before performing regression? I'm thinking that it might be useful to run a regression algorithm on each cluster thereby only including "similar" data points. Or would I simply be losing information?

One concern I had was that a test point at the "edge" of a cluster might be poorly estimated.

Comment: What are your goals?  Inference or pure prediction?

Comment: Main goal is prediction. But I'd also be interested in inference.

Comment: Were you constrained to use linear regression (OLS), or are other methods available?

Comment: I can use any regression algorithm I like.

Comment: I got started on a long answer but got busy.  Short version: standard errors will be too small on coefficiencts of sub-regressions if the clusters themselves are uncertain.  For prediction, consider using a flexible method like a random forest to control for the covariates that you'd use in clustering -- generally you should prefer one-step approaches to two-step approaches where possible.  If the cluster assignments are obvious, consider whether the clusters have different data-generating processes, or if the cluster assignment variable is merely correlated with other, better covariates.

Answer (score 1):

Consider to fit a random-effects regression model. In a random model, your clustering effects is taken into account.